# Connecting node.JS app to Heroku PostgreSQL DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have been having some trouble with connecting my node.JS app to my Heroku database. I had my app working with a locally hosted Postgres database on PGadmin, but when I tried moving towards deploying on Heroku with a Heroku Postgres DB I started getting a variety of errors.

This was my base code that worked locally and that I tried to switch over to Heroku's DB (some variables hidden with ***):

```
const Client = require('pg');
const client = new Client.Client({
    host: "***.amazonaws.com",
    user: "***",
    password: "***",
    database: "***",
    port: 5432,
    ssl: true,
    sslmode: require,
});
```

The "ssl" and "sslmode" were only added when switching over.

I have triple-checked that all the values are correct. When I do it this way this is the error I get...

```
Error: self signed certificate
```

When commenting out the "ssl" part the error changes to...

```
Error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host '***', user '***', database '***' , SSL off
```

I tried researching this pg_hba.conf issue and there was suggestions I add in a line that made sure that a password was not required for all IPv4 connections but this did not change my error messages.

I am quite a bit stuck on how to solve this trouble as I can't quite find any further help online so far.

Comment: This may be due to the version of `pg` that you are using. Try rolling back the version to pre 8.x version. Maybe 7.14.0. This is not quite a solution but rather a work around.

Comment: Would this be rolling back the pg version with node.JS or with Heroku? Do you have any sites I can look further into why this is the case?

Comment: With npm. For instance `npm uninstall pg` followed by `npm install pg@7.14.0`. If that works then you know what the issue is. This is discussed [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2009)

Comment: It does work, thank you. Caused me quite a bit of wrinkles over these past few hours.